# Adding printers by shell script; works in terminal but not as .command

Tags: bash, shell, sh

I am trying to provide a clickable .command to set up printers in Macs for my workplace. I thought since it is something I do very frequently, I can write a shellscript for each printer and save it on a shared server. Then, when I need to add a printer for someone, I can just find the shell script on the server and execute it. My current command works in terminal, but once executed as a .command, it comes up with the errors.

This is my script:

```
#!/bin/sh
lpadmin -p ‘PRINTERNAME’ -D PRINTER\ NAME -L ‘OFFICE’ -v lpd://xx.xx.xx.xx -P /Library/Printers/PPDs/Contents/Resources/Xerox\ WorkCentre\ 7855.gz -o printer-is-shared=false -E​
```

I get this error after running the script:

```
lpadmin: Unknown option “?”.
```

I find this strange, because there is no "?" in the script.

Comment: maybe see what does it show when you replace `lpadmin` with `echo` or maybe `>&2 echo`. Or — having put before a function `function printing { for i in "$@"; do >&2 echo $i; done; }` — with `printing`

Comment: You are using "pretty" quotes, `‘’`, which is almost certainly not what you want. Replace with straight quotes `''`, or just drop them as they have no effect anyway.

Comment: @BenjaminW. not necessarily — they might have happened only when pasting to SO. Errors would probably be more specific about smart quotes — although not necessarily.

Comment: See exactly what is being executed by tmp changing first line to `#!/bin/sh -vx`. Good luck.

Comment: @MichałKrzysztofFeiler Either way, it's something only the OP can clarify, and the question should be updated as necessary.

Answer (score 0):

I have a idea, why not try it like this ? there are huge differences between sh shells, so let me know if it rocks, I have more ideas.

```
#!/bin/sh
PPD="PRINTERNAME"
INFO="PRINTER\ NAME"
LOC="OFFICE"
URI="lpd://xx.xx.xx.xx"
OP ="printer-is-shared=false"
# This parameter P is new to me. Is it the paper-name ?
P="/Library/Printers/PPDs/Contents/Resources/Xerox\ WorkCentre\ 7855.gz"

lpadmin -p "$PPD"  -D "$INFO" -L "$LOC"  -v "$URI" -P "$P" -o "$OP" -E;
```